# How to pass data from a dataframe to chart.js with flask Jinja

Tags: python, flask, chart.js, jinja2

I was developing a web service that analyzes sentences and returns back the top 10.

All the code works as expected and shows the data, I'm using the following code to pass the data to the HTML

```
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pd.read_excel(request.files.get('file'))
        df.to_csv(index=False)
        counter = Counter(df['Short Description'])
        most_common = counter.most_common(10)
        lst = []
        for i in most_common:
            lst.append(i)
        df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Top Values','Search Count'])
        df.to_csv('Top_Values.csv', index=False)
        return render_template("upload.html", column_names=df.columns.values, row_data=list(df.values.tolist()),
                           link_column="Patient ID", zip=zip, labels=df['Top Values'], values=df['Search Count'], upload=True)
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html')
```

Now to show the data in the chart.js I use the following code:

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    var value = [{% for item in values %}
    "{{item}}",
        {% endfor %}];

    var label = [{% for item in labels %}
    "{{item}}",
        {% endfor %}];

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'bar',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: label,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Top Values',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(17, 146, 232)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(17, 146, 232)',
                data: value
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
</script>
```

at this point, the code works as expected and I can visualize the data in the chart, however, on  my visual studio code shows 14 problems, even though the code works perfectly, I'm fairly new to chart.js and I just want to understand better how can I improve my code (the fact that is working doesn't mean it can't be better). I hope you guys can help me to understand what i'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: The fact that a linter throws errors also can't be taken as gospel that you've written bad code. I _don't_ get this with Jinja in VSCode but I don't know what I changed to be different from yours, specifically, on this issue

Comment: I'm not sure why you've wrapped `{% for item in values %}` in a list, though

Comment: I tried to use var value = {values}; var label = {labels}; but the data don't show up to the chart @roganjosh